# limit of object or way to find it

Tags: vb.net

so i need to find the limit of object and prove it
so i have done this

```
    Dim D3 As New CLdevoire
    Dim i As Int64
    Dim j As Int64
    Dim R As Int64
    R = 9223372036854775807 
    For i = 1 To R 
        D3 = New CLdevoire 
        Console.WriteLine(i) 
    Next

    For i = 1 To R 
        For j = 1 To R 
            D3 = New CLdevoire
            Console.WriteLine(i) 
        Next
    Next
```

but either my computer crash because i don't have enough ram or if i have a swap because the disk and ram are
does anyone have a way to reach it ? (since for my teacher they are a limit before the system limit of 2^64

Comment: First, please use English. I had to put the comments in a translator, just to find out they're meaningless. Second, what do you mean by *limit of object*? Third, A loop counting to 2⁶³−1 will never terminate in your lifetime (it’s over 290 years assuming 1 iteration needs 1 ns).

Comment: Well, if you have a crash, then you reached this limit. What did you expect to happen? Btw, you can simply use `While True ... End While` or `Do ... Loop` as infinite  loop.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes but sometime it did not crash at all

Comment: The [garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) reclaims the memory of unreachable objects. You must store all the objects to avoid this. e.g. in a linked list.

Comment: big thank @OlivierJacot-Descombes exactly what i searched

Comment: You are looking for the limit of *what*?

Comment: If your computer can write one million values of i to the console per second (it can't go that fast), it will take it *way* more than 34 million years to complete. You might want to re-think what the problem is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton exactly, I put some code together as a possible answer, and removed Console.WriteLine because it will slow things considerably, but I'm not sure what limit we're testing

Comment: @AndrewMorton "How many object can be created in the main program?" so it hard to re-think what is the problem

Comment: @Valgul I am no expert in the matter, but if you could find out how the objects are stored, perhaps there is some pointer that is 8 bytes in size. Furthermore, storage might be aligned on multiples of 8 bytes for a 64-bit system, so the lowest 3 bits of the pointer might be ignored (or used for something else). That would give a limit. [Managed object internals, Part 1. The layout](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/) looks to be a start into researching it, and a search for ".net managed object object header" could reveal more information.